# Why don't hamsters exhibit a fear response when other hamsters nearby are under attack?

Tags: predation, stress

There is this live feeding video on youtube that displays 30 live hamsters being eaten by 4 bullfrogs. You can find it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz4Or3o-jHA

What struck me as extremely odd was that none of the hamsters exhibited any kind of stress when one of them was being eaten alive.

The first one got eaten head first at 0:28 https://youtu.be/rz4Or3o-jHA?t=208 yet none of the other hamsters tried to run away. Instead, some of them even approached the attacking frog and started sniffing its eyeballs. Then somewhere after 3:25 https://youtu.be/rz4Or3o-jHA?t=206 another hamster is attacked from the side which causes it to scream out in pain. Yet the other hamsters are still unfazed by it. Some are even cleaning their fur as the carnage around them unfolds.
So how does this work. Why do all these hamsters seem so comfortable?

EDIT: At the end a few of the hamsters do seem to freeze a bit, but no real panic. There is another live feeding video that shows a single bullfrog eating a group of mice. You can find it here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RDwz8mjOIw These mice do exhibit real fear. Since both hamsters and mice are part of the same larger family called Muridae, it's very strange that hamsters react so differently.

Comment: This does seem odd indeed. I don't have time to look into and research an answer, but I can't help but notice that "The entire laboratory and pet populations of Syrian hamsters appear to be descendants of a single brother–sister pairing." (Wikipedia) representing one heck of a bottleneck. Inbreeding  may play a part.

Comment: Maybe the hamsters are instead pretty clever and realized they're confined in a death trap and have simply accepted their inevitable fate